# Spark Scala : How to send more than 10 columns to a function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking for pointers on ideal way  to send multiple spark.sql.columns to a function (with out mentioning them individually) . Currently I am passing a single column to a function to derive a new column but I need to send multiple columns to the function. Any suggestion on how I can select specific columns say "Flag1", "Flag2" and so on and send as an  struct or other way ?  and be able to access the column Name and its value  in the called function similar to how I am doing in the below function?

e.g.: just mentioning 3 columns here but I have around 25+ columns and need to almost 10 of them to the function.

var data = Seq(("10","value1","value2"), ("20","value2","value3"), ("30","value4","value5")).toDF("id","Flag1","Flag2")

```
data.withColumn("newCol",doSomething($"Flag1")).show(5)

def doSomething(flag:Column): Column ={
    when(flag.isNotNull && flag === lit("value4"),"abc")
    .when(flag.isNotNull && flag === lit("vaue5"),"xyz")
    .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    
}
```

Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: You could pass the dataframe as a parameter and use it in a way you want. In that case you won't have any needs to pass columns as you can easily get all the columns from the dataframe.

Comment: Thank you. since I am calling this function in dataframe.withcolumn , does passing  the dataframe will give the context of that row or it will send the full dataset ?  I tried something like this data.withColumn("newcolumn",test(struct(data.columns.map(data(_)) : _*))
def test(Array[Row]): Column ={

    val temp = r.getAs[String]("Flag1")
    when(temp.isNotNull && temp == lit("value4"),lit("abc")
    .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    
}

error: package org.apache.spark.sql.test is not a value
       data.withColumn("newc",test(struct(data.columns.map(data(_)) : _*))

Comment: To use it with withcolumn operation you will have to register a udf and then use it.

Comment: @NikunjKakadiya thank you. In my team , i was told not to use the UDF so thats I am calling a function in the withColumn Operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just have multiple arguments in the function definition?

e.g.

```
data.withColumn("newcolumn", doSomething(data.columns.map(col))) 

def doSomething(flags: Array[Column]): Column = {
    flag1 = flags(0)
    flag2 = flags(1)
    when(flag1.isNotNull && flag2 === lit("value4"),"abc")
    .when(flag1.isNotNull && flag2 === lit("vaue5"),"xyz")
    .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mck , I need to pass 10+(could end up with 22 )  columns to the function , so wondering  is there a better way to pass these <N> columns , like a struct or some other optimal way. I tried  the below but giving error  data.withColumn("newcolumn",test(struct(data.columns.map(data()) : _*)) def test(Array[Row]): Column ={ val temp = r.getAs[String]("Flag1") when(temp.isNotNull && temp == lit("value4"),lit("abc") .otherwise(lit("unknown")) } error: package org.apache.spark.sql.test is not a value data.withColumn("newc",test(struct(data.columns.map(data()) : _*))

Comment: @novice8989 how about the edited answer? you can pass a seq of column

Comment: Thank you very much sir @mck. if may I ask, is there anyway  I can refer the column inside the doSomething function by name like  flag1 = flags["Flag1"] Is that possible. or only its by ordinal position.  thanks again.

Comment: if you know the column name, you can just use `$"Flag1"`. There is no need to get it from the seq of column.

Comment: sorry I didnt understood please pardon  me. Are you saying  I can directly say  tempFlag = $"Flag1" without referring to the Flags parameter , please note this is inside the doSomething Function()

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Column objects can be instantiated without being attached to a dataframe.

Comment: So actually you don't even need to pass any parameters into the function

Comment: But i see in all the code samples that dataframe.withColumn("newcol") operation has the fn(col("1"), col("2") )being sent to the function to calculate the new column value.  If possible could you  please point to any documentation sorry for extending this discussion

Comment: The column objects do not hold any data. They are just "pointers" to the column in some sense.  Passing them around will not affect the performance.

Comment: unfortunately , i am getting error while trying to pass data.columns.  def doSomeThing(flags: Seq[Column]): Column ={
     when(flags(0) === lit ("value5"),lit("abc"))
    .otherwise(lit("unknown"))
    
}

var data = Seq(("10","value1","value2"), ("20","value2","value3"), ("30","value4","value5")).toDF("id","Flag1","Flag2")

data.withColumn("newcolumn",doSomeThing(data.columns)).show()

<console>:335: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Array[String]
 required: Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]
       data.withColumn("newcolumn",doSomeThing(data.columns)).show()

Comment: sorry about that, please check the edited answer @novice8989

Comment: Thanks much it worked. I know you mentioned , no need to refer to the Array[Column] parameter but I am still trying to wrap my head around.  Any other way to access these column values by name using the passed in Array[Column]) , just curious if possible for my my learning purpose.

Comment: If you know the name of the column, why would you need to get it from the list of column names? It's meaningless to get an array element by name if you know its name. You can just use the name directly.

Comment: Thank you. I checked directly accessing $"Flag1" in the function.it worked but given I have the different data frames in the same spark session and have the  same field name. Does it still work and figure out the right field from the right data frame. assuming I have 2 dataframe with same field name with different data in the same spark session.  I am just learning so kindly pardon my lack of knowledge on this

Comment: Yes. Columns are only defined when they are attached to a dataframe.